# Get identical Array from increments to 2 values

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I want to find the minimum number to be subtracted to get from an array like this

```
[8, 10, 5]
```

to an array like this

```
[3, 3, 3]
```

I am only allowed to change the values of TWO indexes (in this case either index 0 and 1 OR index 1 and 2). I am only allowed to subtract values and have to subtract the same value over both indexes(ex. If I wanted to subtract 5 I'd have to do it on two indexes, either index 0 and 1 or index 2 and 3).

Edit: Clarification #1: There is no "base value". Just that all indexes are identical through the lowest number of subtraction values (not operations, but values subtracted.)

Clarification #2: At any given time, I am only allowed to subtract the same value from 2 indexes, and only 2

I am not sure of how to tackle this problem, any smallest hints and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so, what did you try?

Comment: At any given time when you perform the subtract operation, it has to be from 2 indices, is this correct?

Comment: is it also mentioned that you cannot change value at index 0 and index 2?

Comment: No, I am allowed to change the values at whatever indexes I want, as long as it is restricted to two indexes, and that the same value is subtracted when changing them.

Comment: is time complexity a matter of concern ?

Comment: For this, time complexity is not a very big matter of concern. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make all the values identical, that means your lowest and highest value should be equal.
for example, in your array

```
arr[] = {8,5,10};
```

You need to first sort it.

```
 arr[] = {5,8,10};
```

Now, you see that the difference between the highest and lowest is 5,
therefore you subtract 5 from the 2 maximum elements

```
 arr[] = {5,3,5};
```

then again you sort it

```
arr[] = {3,5,5};
```

now the difference between maximum and minimum 2, therefore you subtract it from the maximum 2 elements present in your array .
and your array becomes this

```
  arr[] = {3,3,3};
```

The idea is to bring the maximum number closest to the smallest number and that happens if you subtract the difference between them from the maximum number.